# Keep ASP.NET core app running all the time in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am hosting an ASP.NET Core (2.2) app in IIS.

The app is using a custom app pool with below settings:

```
.NET CLR version: No Managed Code
Start Mode: Always Running
Idle Time-out (minutes): 0
```

My startup code looks like:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseStartup<MyStartup>() 
  .Build() 
  .Run();
```

I am expecting that the app will always run, but after some time the app stops after getting below request:

> [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost] Request starting
>   HTTP/1.1 POST
>   http://127.0.0.1:43745/app/iisintegration  0 
>   [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost] Request finished in
>   5.7107ms 202

The app is a sub app. The parent app is using different app pool, and does have idle time-out.

Is there some setting I am missing to keep the app up all the time ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Found a solution which is working. You need to host your ASP.NET Core 2.2 app using in-process hosting model. Below steps can be followed for it.

1. Install Application Initialization Module (IIS)

Server Manager > Add roles and Features > Server Roles > Web Server (IIS) > Application Development > Application Initialization

2. IIS > Your App Pool > Start Mode > Always Running
3. IIS > Your App Pool > Idle Time-out > 0
4. IIS > Your App > Advanced Settings > Preload Enabled > True
5. Setup your app for In-Process hosting model (web.config changes for Asp.net core module and code changes to set correct current directory)

More information can be found at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2
- https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12232
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2
- https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6075

Comment: "Preload Enabled" feature is what i have been missing for a long time.

Comment: It should also include loading CLR https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html#making-asp-net-core-application-always-running-on-iis

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer above - it works in most circumstances but it was not working for me and the reason was that I was using windows authentication and had an authorization requirement for every part of my application including the root.

When you have Preload Enabled set, IIS will attempt to awaken your app after recycling the app pool (usually after being idle for 1740 minutes) but it will get a 401 and will fail to awaken your app if the request cannot be authorized.

This means you will need to do two things if you are using windows authentication:

1. Within IIS allow anonymous authentication along with windows authentication
2. Within Program.cs, make sure you are not forcing every request to be authorized as a fall back policy. If you have the following code then disable the Fallback policy (or better yet add a custom policy that will just be applied to your controllers:

   ```
   builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
       // try removing the fallback policy so that static html pages in wwwroot don't have to be authorized and can be accessed anonymously
       //options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
   });
   ```

Here is an example of a custom authorization policy that is applied just to controllers:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // try removing the fallback policy so that static html pages in wwwroot don't have to be authorized and can be accessed anonymously
    //options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;

    // Create an authorization policy which will be applied just to controllers and nothing else (denies anonymous access)
    options.AddPolicy("DenyAnonymous",
        new AuthorizationPolicy(new IAuthorizationRequirement[] {
            new DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement()
        },
        new string[] {
            NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        }));
});

// Make sure our controllers can convert dates and times from json and that they all require authorization
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddMvcOptions(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("DenyAnonymous")));
```