# how to make background service run in iis even if iis is idle

Tags: .net-6.0, backgroundworker, iis-8

i am implementing a background service , the problem is when i run it in local it is working fine since the app is hit and running . but in iis i deployed code and started the server in iis. the background service is not running until i browse the site and becoming idle when the server is idle

My program. cs
builder.Services.AddHostedService();

i have registered it also

the main problem is i cant create a windows service or a console app since i it is not approved in my org.

````
```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.InkML;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2016.Drawing.ChartDrawing;
using handbook.Controllers.HR;
using handbook.Data;
using handbook.Models.Mail;
using handbook.Repositories.Implementation;
using handbook.Repositories.Interface;
using handbook.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

namespace handbook.BackgroundmailService
{
    public class EmailReminderSenderService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        private Timer _timer;
        private readonly IOauthMailService _emailSender;
        private readonly ILogger<EmailReminderSenderService> _logger;

        public EmailReminderSenderService(IOauthMailService emailSender, ILogger<EmailReminderSenderService> logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _logger = logger;
            Services = serviceProvider;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

        private static TimeSpan getJobRunDelay()
        {
            // Change the delay to run every 10 minutes
            return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Background service is started");
            _timer = new Timer(SendEmails, null, getJobRunDelay(), getJobRunDelay());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
public async void SendEmails(object state)
        {
my task
}
public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Background service is stopping");
            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57523899/keep-asp-net-core-app-running-all-the-time-in-iis?

Comment: @Martheen i have made all the changes in iss . but still it is not starting .

Comment: It’s designed that way, so your likely hope is to get approval to deploy it as Windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS typically does not start background services on its own, it relies on requests that trigger application startup. Currently, you can [configure IIS to always run the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944538/prevent-iis-from-idle-timeout-when-running-background-tasks), but this is not a good workaround.

To keep a background service running, you may want to look for alternatives; after all, IIS is designed for hosting Web applications, not long-running background services.

You mentioned that your organization doesn't approve the creation of Windows services, but you may want to discuss this with your IT department. Hosting an application as a Windows service is the most common way to run a long-lived background process on a Windows computer.